# Change Colours of all Black Pixels in Pygame

Tags: python, colors, pygame, pixel

I'm making a program with the Pygame that changes the overall colours of inserted pictures.  It works fine, but  now I'd like to change specific portions of the picture - only black.  Is there a method that changes the colours of *all* black pixels to an alternative colour?

I've already tried using `surface.set_at()`, `surface.get_at()` as well as a few others.  Help please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

may be you should try [PixelArray](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html)

from the documentation :

**PixelArray.replace**

```
Replaces the passed color in the PixelArray with another one.
PixelArray.replace (color, repcolor, distance=0, weights=(0.299, 0.587, 0.114)): Return None
Replaces the pixels with the passed color in the PixelArray by changing them them to the passed replacement color.
```

Comment: Perfect, but being slightly more specific would have allowed it to be done a little quicker.  Regardless, thanks a lot for you help.  It's working now. :)